# peazip: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6

Tags: shared-library

I'm trying to get `peazip` running but I'm facing some trouble.
When I run `peazip` I get the error:

```
peazip: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

From what I searched, I need to install `emul-linux-x86-compat` and `emul-linux-x86-gtklibs`. However, I didn't find those packages.

How can I resolve this ??

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59115034/7940996) resolved this issue for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install ia32-libs and it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to install i32lib first open a Terminal and type the following;

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386 
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6:i386
```

and then type:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```