# How to install LASSPTools?

Tags: 12.04

How do I install LASSPTools on Ubuntu 12.04?
http://www.lassp.cornell.edu/LASSPTools/LASSPTools.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Download `LASSPTools.linux.entire.tar.gz` from this page: http://www.lassp.cornell.edu/lassp_pub/
2. Open a terminal and go to the directory where you downloaded `LASSPTools.linux.entire.tar.gz`, then extract the archive with `tar`:

   ```
   tar -xvzf LASSPTools.linux.entire.tar.gz
   ```
3. LASSPTools binaries are now in the `LASSPTools/bin_linux/` folder.

---

If you get the error below when running one of the tools, you might want to compile the binaries yourself from the sources. Otherwise you could try this : [peazip: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388943/peazip-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libx11-so-6)

```
./polydraw: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: how can  compile the binaries yourself from the sources

Comment: Source files are in the LASSPTools/src directory. You will find all the informations you need in the README file (LASSPTools/ folder).